# Bode Plots - Absolute Value of Complex Function in Magnitude calculation

Tags: bode-plot, control-theory

I'm struggling with one step in the magnitude calculation during manual Bode plotting. Specifically during the step of applying the absolute value to \$s = jw\$, what is the reasoning for why you can so nonchalantly disregard any imaginary terms that occur? Obviously I must have misunderstood something, but the examples I've seen skip this step without further explanation.

Where exactly in the calculations below do I go wrong?

$$
G(s) = \frac{1}{s+1}\\
|G(jw)|_{dB} = 20\lg\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{jw+1}\right)^2}\right)  \\
= 20\lg\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{1^2}{j^2w^2+2jw+1^2}\right)}\right) = 20\lg\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{-w^2+2jw+1}\right)}\right) \\
= 10(\lg\left(1\right)-\lg\left(-w^2+2jw+1\right)) 
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do some revision on complex numbers, e.g. the magnitude of a complex number, \$(a+jb)\$, is \$\sqrt{ (a^2+b^2)}\$ and not \$\sqrt{(a+jb)^2}\$, which is meaningless in this context - you should recognise that \$\sqrt {(a+jb)^2} = a+jb\$. Similarly, the phase angle of  \$(a+jb)\$ is \$arctan (\frac{b}{a})\$.

Magnitude and phase angle are scalar quantities, therefore there can't be any 'j' terms in these expressions.